# Can you put networking methods in an NSManagedObject subclass?

Tags: ios, multithreading, networking, core-data, thread-safety

I have an `NSManagedObject` subclass to represent a person on Flickr. I have to grab all the properties to be stored in Core Data of the internet with a URL request. I want to put the functions to grab the data off the web in the Person class. However, the request will be done asynchronously, and the properties will be set on the object in a completion block. Will this cause an error because Core Data is not thread safe?Would it be best to have a seperate class for loading, or would the `NSManagedObject` Subclass work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would put it in a separate class. Not so much for the different threads issue (which is relatively simple to solve by using `NSManagedObjectContext`'s `performBlock:` method), but for your separation of concerns. The data model should just store the data. It shouldn't have to worry about downloading it. Create a class that downloads the data, and then pass raw data to the `NSManagedObject` subclass (a method named `+objectFromDownloadedData:(NSData *)` comes to mind) to create an actual data object that your app can work with.

Answer (score 0):

You could put networking code in an `NSManagedObject` subclass.

It would be **spectacularly** poor design to do so, however. Putting networking code in a model class is just terrible app architecture. It could work, but it will be some of the ugliest, most awful code ever seen on iOS.